# How to find condition in SQL query and replace it 1=1 with Java

Tags: java

I have sql query which has a conditions(in where clause, having clause, or in join). I need to find condition which contains value with brackets like this: {some name} and replace that condition with 1=1(in some cases) with java.

E.g.

```
Select *
From customer c inner join address a on c.id = a.customer_id
where c.id > {var1} AND (c.name LIKE {var2} OR  a.city = {var3})  AND ... (there could be written all posible operaters and conditions which are allowed by sql)

if var1 = 2, var2 = *ALL, var3 = 'aa' then query should looks like

Select *
From customer c inner join address a on c.id = a.customer_id
where c.id > 2 AND (1=1 OR  a.city = 'aa')
```

I thought to split where condition with AND|OR then check if it contains {var2} then replace with 1=1, but this will not work. (in above described example after the split it will be  (c.name LIKE {var2} so ( also will be replaced).

Does somebody came across with this situation and how solved.
Is there any open source libraray which will  find and replace or how can I do that with regex ?

Comment: You want to write some complicated query then replace it with 1=1 if not required ? I am not recommending that kind of approach. It is better if you generate where statement dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I assume you are **not** able to dynamically build your sql. For this you would go the trivial way and could build your sql using string concats, e.g.

```
"select ... where c.id > " + myvalue + " ... "
```

The use of regular expressions for sqls will work, if you can guarantee that your expression will only find the specific parts of your sql and not more. This sounds a bit trivial but is hard to achieve for specific sqls, e.g.:

```
select '{var2}' from mytable
```

Should **{var2}** replaced here or not? I think not, because it is part of a string literal and is not part of a where statement.

Therefore you need a more structured look at your sql which is provided by a sql parser.

Using e.g. JSqlParser (https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) you would be able to identify the parts of your where statement and replace the parts of your SQL in a controlled manner.

But to get this parsing going, you have to replace your **{val}** with something that is SQL conform, e.g. **__val__**.

So your replacement could be achieved with something like the following code. It assumes, that the replacement is only done within the right expression, but you could easily change that.

```
String sqlTxt = "Select * from customer c inner join address a on c.id = a.customer_id where c.id > {var1} AND (c.name LIKE {var2} OR  a.city = {var3})";

//replace macro constructs
String sql = sqlTxt.replace("{", "__").replace("}", "__");

//build replacement data    
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("__var1__", "2");
data.put("__var2__", "*ALL");
data.put("__var3__", "'aa'");

//parse sql
Select select = (Select) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);

StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(sql);

//rewrite sql to fit your needs
((PlainSelect) select.getSelectBody()).getWhere().accept(new ExpressionVisitorAdapter() {
    int delta = 0;  //to correct the position due to former replacements

    @Override
    protected void visitBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression expr) {
        if (expr instanceof ASTNodeAccess) {
            if (expr.getRightExpression() instanceof Column) {
                Column c = ((Column) expr.getRightExpression());

                if (data.containsKey(c.getColumnName())) {
                    if ("__var2__".equals(c.getColumnName())) {
                        delta = replaceASTNodeWith(b, delta, (ASTNodeAccess) expr, "1=1");
                    } else {
                        delta = replaceASTNodeWith(b, delta, (ASTNodeAccess) expr,  
                                expr.getLeftExpression() + expr.getStringExpression() + data.get(c.getColumnName()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        super.visitBinaryExpression(expr);
    }
});

System.out.println("parsed  sql = " + select.toString());
System.out.println("changed sql = " + b.toString());
```

The replacement in your sql is somewhat tricky due to the position change of former replacements.

```
//do the text replacement within the sql
private static int replaceASTNodeWith(StringBuilder sql, int delta, ASTNodeAccess node, String expr) {
        sql.replace(
                node.getASTNode().jjtGetFirstToken().absoluteBegin + delta - 1,
                 node.getASTNode().jjtGetLastToken().absoluteEnd + delta - 1,
                 expr);
        return delta + expr.length() 
                 - (node.getASTNode().jjtGetLastToken().absoluteEnd - node.getASTNode().jjtGetFirstToken().absoluteBegin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not answer your question, but just more a suggestion on how I used the 1=1 approach.

I think you might want to write something like this

```
String query = "select * from customer c inner join address a on c.id = a.customer_id  where 1=1"
if(var1 != null)
  query += "and c.id > " + var1
if(var2 != null)
  query += "and c.name LIKE " + var2
if(var3 != null)
  query += "and a.city = " + var3
```

for example you want to had that logic, it will be a little tricky that it will look like this.

```
//you should realize that 1=1 here to make sure that we add "AND " command
String query = "select * from customer c inner join address a on c.id = a.customer_id  where 1=1"
if(var1 != null)
  query += "and c.id > " + var1
if(var2 != null && var3 != null) { //because if var2 or var3 is all, then return all.
  query += "and ( c.name LIKE " + var2;
  query += "or a.city = " + var3 + ")";
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

use the following:-
In case of single word variable between {singleWord}

```
queryString = queryString.replaceAll("\\{[A-Za-z0-9]+\\}", "1=1");
```

In case of multi word variable between {multi word}

```
queryString = queryString.replaceAll("\\{[A-Za-z0-9\\s]+\\}", "1=1");
```

Refer for more details:- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum